# Regex expression to refuse numeric sequences, such as "1234"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, regex, validation

Using old webforms app...and...

Looking for help with a regex expression that won't allow numeric sequences such as '1234' but will allow 123 or 456 or 455 etc...just not 1234, 2345, 4567 etc...

So what I would like:

hello123  PASS 
hello1234 FAIL 
hello1244 PASS 
hello1111 PASS 
hello4567 FAIL 
hello4566 PASS

So far I have got:
.*\d{4}

which includes all CONSECTUIVE numbers, so anything with 4 numbers fails
dsfjs123     PASS 
kdfjs23      PASS 
fsjk1234     FAIL 
1233sdflkds  FAIL 
23dklfjsk    PASS 
skfj24354lkj FAIL 
dkfjsd23kjdlkj PASS

from:
https://www.regextester.com/114733

**Is this even possible what im asking for? i've been doing alot of research online and can't seem to find it?**

Also...I would like to NOT ALLOW Alphabetic sequences, such as "abc"
so:
ABC FAIL 
ABB PASS 
BBC PASS 
BCD FAIL

any help or even a point in the right direction would be very much appreciated thank you

Comment: `Is this even possible` - if it is, it'd be a complex regex (long, not complex as such) - have you considered NOT using a regex? anyway, what do you have against the words THIRSTY, NOPE, AFGHANISTAN and STUDENT :p

Comment: Get the numbers using `\d` and process them separately. It will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match()` with the pattern `1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890`:

```js
var inputs = ["hello123", "hello1234", "hello1244", "hello1111", "hello4567", "hello4566"];
inputs.forEach(i => console.log(i.match(/1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890/) ? (i + " => FAIL") : (i + " => PASS")));
```

The regex alternation used above simply tries to find any of the 7 disallowed 4 length numerical sequences.

Comment: then add `abc`, `bcd`, `cde` ..... `xyz` :p long :p

Comment: @JaromandaX We can programatically build out that alternation...it's not that bad.

Comment: Simple as that and to negate we can do: ^(?!.*1234|.*2345|.*4567|.*5678|.*6789|.*7890|.*abc).*$    Thank you kindly good sir!

Comment: although already solved, i was intrigued by the idea of autogenerating these group-matches: https://gist.github.com/SeidChr/5f0c0fd4097a52bfeea24866547f9b6b